# PHP multiple answer quiz - checking for correct answer combinations

Tags: php

Trying my first steps with PHP programming a quiz that allows multiple answers though **only** a certain combination like answer option 2 & 3 should give you a score. Containing the values is not enough, so simply picking all answers should result in no score.

Everything works so far, but the condition checking for the correct answer and incrementing the score doesn't work and I have no clue why. I have no one to ask, so I'm relying on you. Who could enlighten me, please?

My HTML:

```
<form action="result.php" method="post" id="quiz">
 <div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="question-1-answers[]" id="question-1-answers-A" value="A" />
  <label for="question-1-answers-A">ABCD </label>
 </div>

 <div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="question-1-answers[]" id="question-1-answers-B" value="B" />
  <label for="question-1-answers-B">EFGH</label>
 </div>

 <div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="question-1-answers[]" id="question-1-answers-C" value="C" />
  <label for="question-1-answers-C">KLMN</label>
 </div>

 <div>
   <input type="checkbox" name="question-1-answers[]" id="question-1-answers-D" value="D" />
   <label for="question-1-answers-D">OPQR</label>
 </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit Quiz" />
</form>
```

My result.php:

```
<?php
  $totalscore = 0;

  if(!empty($_POST['question-1-answers'])) {               
  echo "You selected the following answer(s): <br/>";
foreach($_POST['question-1-answers'] as $selected) {
echo $selected;

     // now checking if answer was the right combination
 if ($selected == "BC") {
     echo ('condition met!');
 $totalscore++;
 }
    }

   echo "<div id='results'>$totalscore out of 1</div>";
   }
 ?>
```

Even if I choose B & C, the condition never fires. The Content of $selected is showing the correct answer though. ("BC") in this case.

Why is it not firing? What am I overlooking here?

Comment: `if ($selected == "BC")` you can't check that from separate inputs. Check if it's equal to one and/or the other.

Comment: There is no `<input ... />` with a value of `BC` so `if ($selected == "BC")` will never be true. You probably want to concatenate your `$selected` values together in there where you've got that `echo` statement atm; then do the check outside the loop.

Comment: You should use `isset()` (with && =='x') for checkboxes, not `empty()`.

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['question-1-answers'])) { $result = implode('', $_POST['question-1-answers']); } if($result === 'BC') ...` - quick 'n' dirty

Answer (score 0):

$_POST['question-1-answers'] is an array so you need to check if B and C is in

Try something like

```
if(in_array($_POST['question-1-answers'], 'A') && in_array($_POST['question-1-answers'], 'B'))
   $totalScore++;
```

Or if you dont want to many conditions

```
$selected = '';
foreach ($_POST['question-1-answers'] as $key => $value) {
    $selected .= $value;
}
if($selected == 'BC')
    $totalScore++;
```

Comment: Thanks! But assuming A & B are the correct answers and the user choosing "A" & "B" & "C" - won't the condition be true, because A + B ARE there ... unfortunately C too, which should give 0 Points. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah sure i make a misstake, the second solution should work, your string will be ABC so the condition is'nt meet

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach($_POST['question-1-answers'] as $selected) {
echo $selected; // your var will be B, then C if both were selected by player

// now checking if answer was the right combination
if ($selected == "BC") { 
// here, you try checking if 'B equals BC' or if 'C equals BC'
// no matter what player answered, it'll never match
// YOU ARE IN A LOOP -> one round / one answer
 echo ('condition met!'); // will never be true
$totalscore++;
}
}
```

> You need to concatenate your var `$selected` IN THE LOOP, then, outside the loop, compare to right answers combination